# How do I store date values partially?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime

I'm using MS SQL Server 2005 and I need to store date values partially. For example, the day part of a date may remain unknown in fact but MS SQL Server constrains to specify the full date like the follow:

```
INSERT foo(dt) VALUES('2001-10-31');
```

I would like to use something like this though:

```
INSERT foo(dt) VALUES ('2001-10-??');
```

Of course, MS SQL cannot accept such a date, and I've found a rough example that converts date parts into multipliers:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
CREATE TABLE foo ( 
    dt INT 
) 
INSERT foo VALUES ( 
    DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) * 10000 
        + DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) * 100 
        + DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) 
) 
SELECT dt FROM foo 
DROP TABLE foo
```

... hm, I can't believe whether it's the only way to solve the problem, so I would like to ask: how do I resolve this issue in the best way?

Thanks in advance.

---

UPD 2014:
Also see [Storing partial dates in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501619/storing-partial-dates-in-a-database)

Comment: Why don't you know the full date? What use is date field without a full date?

Comment: sometimes the day part of a date is really unknown. for example, i can fill in a rarity unreleased music demo record, but the record can be either misdated or partially dated not indicating the day of record. so i would like to reserve the possibility of postponed filling in the record information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you can store each date part, and still constrain them to a valid date:

```
CREATE Table PartialDates
(
     YearPart       smallint --(2 bytes -32k to +32k)
    ,MonthPart      tinyint  --(1 byte 0 to 255)
    ,DayPart        tinyint  --(1 byte 0 to 255)
    ,CompleteDate  AS (CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(10),YearPart)+'-'+CONVERT(varchar(10),MonthPart)+'-'+CONVERT(varchar(10),coalesce(DayPart,1))))
)
ALTER TABLE dbo.PartialDates ADD CONSTRAINT
    CK_PartialDates_IsDate CHECK (ISDATE(CONVERT(varchar(10),YearPart)+'-'+CONVERT(varchar(10),MonthPart)+'-'+CONVERT(varchar(10),coalesce(DayPart,1)))=1)
GO

insert into PartialDates (yearpart,monthpart,daypart) values(2009,91,1) --error
insert into PartialDates (yearpart,monthpart,daypart) values(2009,1,1)  --ok
insert into PartialDates (yearpart,monthpart,daypart) values(2009,1,51) --error
insert into PartialDates (yearpart,monthpart,daypart) values(2009,2,29) --error
insert into PartialDates (yearpart,monthpart,daypart) values(2009,2,28) --ok
insert into PartialDates (yearpart,monthpart,daypart) values(2009,2,null)--ok

select * from PartialDates

YearPart MonthPart DayPart CompleteDate
-------- --------- ------- -----------------------
2009     1         1       2009-01-01 00:00:00.000
2009     2         28      2009-02-28 00:00:00.000
2009     2         NULL    2009-02-01 00:00:00.000

(3 row(s) affected
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered storing your month, day, and year in separate columns?  It would be a very rudimentart & simplistic approach but sometimes that's the way to go.  This would allow you to easily query values for a particular month and/or day without a lot of type conversions that may confuse the heck out of someone else that may need to work on the code down the road.

Comment: I would not normally recommend this, but if you don't know the day, I dont see how else to do it without horrible manipulation. You could also add a real date field that populates from a trigger if one of the three fields is changed and only if all three make up a valid date. Then where you have valid dates, you could query using
date functions if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Smart date keys are definitely the way to go. Your code is a little long, though, as SQL Server does provide a quick way to get it, using [`convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
select cast(convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 112) as int)
```

You would think that you could `convert` this straight to an `int`, but it doesn't work. So you have to convert to a `varchar` and then an `int`.

If you want it to be `00` for the day, in lieu of the actual day:

```
select cast(convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) as int) - day(getdate())
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: thank you for reply, Eric. i'm taking a good look at your advice for the present