# Storing partial dates in a database

Tags: sql, database-design, schema

I want to store partial dates in a relational database (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.). For example, input may just be the year (2013); the year and month (2013-08); or the year, month, and day (2013-08-29). I cannot just use a normal DATE type, as the year will be expanded to 2013-01-01, and this indistinguishable from having the year, month, and day.

I have thought of either separating the date into three separate fields (year, month, and day as integers), but I lose all date niceties in the DBS and have to manage more indicies.

My other thought is to store it as a DATE and have another column saying how precise the date is. For example, '2013-08-01' and 'month' would mean the date is only precise up to the month (2013-08). '2013-08-01' and 'day' would mean the date is fully 2013-08-01.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Please put some codes.

Comment: This seems icky. I can't think of a clean/simple way to represent said data.

Comment: What sort of queries do you want to run?

Comment: +1, I'm surprised this isn't a more common problem (and therefore that there isn't a better solution than the hacks in the answers). At work I regularly (to my annoyance) receive letters from third parties with a date like "July 2019".

Comment: I have just discovered that MySQL / MariaDB allow you to use a `0` in place of an unknown date part. For example `2013-00-00`. That’s remarkably useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there're two possible ways to go:

**(1)** Store **substrings** of date, like:

```
'2013'               -- year 2013 
'2013-01'            -- year 2013, January
'2013-01-01'         -- year 2013, January 1
```

**(2)** Store **3 different columns**, Year, Month, Day (and you can build index Year + Month + Date with no proble)

```
2013  null  null     -- year 2013 
2013     1  null     -- year 2013, January
2013     1     1     -- year 2013, January 1st
```

Which one is the best depends on how do you want to query data. Suppose you have stored procedure and you want to pass a parameter to get all rows falling into condition.

In case **(1)**, you pass string `@Date = '2013-01'` as a parameter and you want to get all rows where year = 2013 and month = 01. So the `where` clause would be like:

```
where left(Date, len(@Date)) = @Date
```

In case **(2)**, you pass three parameters - `@Year = 2013, @Month = 1, @Day = null` and the `where` clause would be something like:

```
where
    Year = @Year and -- Supposing @Year is always not null
    (@Month is null or @Month is not null and Month = @Month) and
    (@Day is null or @Day is not null and Day = @Day)
```

It could be more complex depending on how do you want to process rows. For example, if you give parameter like `2013-01`, do you want to get rows where month = null or not?

On the other hand, if you want to pass date and check if it falls into date range, then Gordon Linoff suggestion is a good one to use.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the best way is to treat these as spans of time and to have an `effdate` and `enddate`.  The you can represent any time span you want.  A year would be like '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31'.  A single date would be like '2013-08-28' and '2013-08-28'.

This would also give you the flexibility to expand the representation to handle quarters or other groups of time.

Comment: I might store a year as "2012-01-01" (inclusive) to "2013-01-01" exclusive.  A day would be "2013-08-28" (inclusive) to "2013-08-29" (exclusive).  Makes it easier to determine if a date/time is in the range if you make the `EndDate` exclusive and the `StartDate` inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've specified, you don't want to use `date_trunc` because you want `2013-08` to mean "the month of August, 2013" and not an actual date!  So you seem to care less about *instants*, and more about *periods*.

I think you should just store strings.  If you store:

```
2013
2013-08
2013-09-25
```

as strings you should be fine.  They sort just fine.  Plus you will only need one column.  If you use two columns, your data might look funny.  For instance, if you store

```
2013-09-04  |  MONTH
```

one might wonder why the `4` is there.

Then again, you might get a malformed string with my suggestion.

Another idea is to make your strings [ISO 8601 Time intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals).  Your database system may even have a time interval type.

Comment: The trouble with storing strings is that you can't easily do arithmetic on them to find the number of months between 2013-08 and 2014-02, for example.  Then again, you can't do that with most of the other alternatives either.