# Add MySQL date (month-day) that accounts for every year

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm making a web app in PHP that calculates vacations and some are fixed, say for example, Christmas, so instead of adding dates like

2015-12-25

2016-12-25

2017-12-25

2018-12-25

Is there any way to add something like

*-12-25

That accounts for every 25th of December of ALL the years? I know PHP has this but since I'm getting the dates from a Vacation Dates table that is populated by the admin I can't figure out how to do this in PHP, else I'll have to default to add 10 years to each entered date

Comment: and what happen in your table? do you want it show *-12-25 in vacation dates column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing partial dates in a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501619/storing-partial-dates-in-a-database)

Comment: You should probably add them for every year.  In all likelihood, you be using `join` or `in` for the comparison and that will require that the date be there.

Comment: With PHP I can format it to show only December 25 for example, but since I got a cycle that goes trough the Vacations table and adds a day to the end date if there is a vacation day between, but I don't want to add 10 rows or have the user add each vacation year by year for simplicity's sake